# How to reject the input

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

The program is exiting when I did not enter "y" in "while" part. Please help me to reject when the user input is not "y"

```
try  {
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.println("hakdug");
  System.out.println("a.quit");
  System.out.println("b.continue");
  System.out.println("c.break");
  System.out.println("d.exit");

  do {
    System.out.print("Enter your choice:");
    choice = br.readLine();
    if (choice.compareTo("b")==0) {
      System.out.println("Congratulation!");
      break;
    }
    else System.out.println("Incorrect!");

    System.out.print("Again? press y to continue:");
    con =br.readLine();
  } while (con.compareTo("y")==0);

} catch(IOException e){}
```

Comment: So just to be clear, the program is meant to loop indefinitely until you press "y" to stop?

Comment: It helps if you provide indents in the code so that it makes it easier for others to review. I've formatted it for you now. Also, it's bad practice to just have a catch block that does nothing -- at the very least, use e.printStackTrace(); to log the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the break statement in your code:

```
try{
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("hakdug");
System.out.println("a.quit");
System.out.println("b.continue");
System.out.println("c.break");
System.out.println("d.exit");


do
{

System.out.print("Enter your choice:");
choice =br.readLine();

if (choice.compareTo("b")==0)
{
System.out.println("Congratulation!");
//break;
}
else System.out.println("Incorrect!");

System.out.print("Again? press y to continue:");
con =br.readLine();
} while (con.compareTo("y")==0);

}catch(IOException e){}
```

The break statement is forcing the JVM to break the entire loop. I have commented the break statement here.

Answer (score 0):

So right now you are going to have an infinite loop if the user enters the letter "y" (Also, this is case sensitive). However, the main thing is if the user puts any other character, it is exiting the program because it reaches the end of file, if you want it to do something else for any other key input, you need to program that in. I would also say that removing the break statement is important because that could cause issues as well.

```
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("hakdug");
        System.out.println("a.quit");
        System.out.println("b.continue");
        System.out.println("c.break");
        System.out.println("d.exit");

        do
          {
           System.out.print("Enter your choice:");
           choice =br.readLine();

           if (choice.compareTo("b")==0)
             {
               System.out.println("Congratulations!");
               //break;
             }
          else 
               System.out.println("Incorrect!");

          System.out.print("Again? press y to continue:");
          con =br.readLine();
         } 
while (con.compareTo("y")==0);

}catch(IOException e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused by the question.

However, if the desired functionality is that you continuously loop until the user gets pressed "b" (and is congratulated) or if they get it wrong then only exits if they press "y" then you should change

```
            } while (con.compareTo("y")==0);
```

to

```
            } while (!(con.compareTo("y")==0));
```

This tells it to loop only if they have not pressed "y" rather than looping when they have pressed "y".